# TFS 2008 Merge/Resolve Conflict Tutorial

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am just wondering if anyone know of a good resource/tutorial/video for explaining the "Resolve Conflict" and the "Merge Tool" in TFS 2008.

I just need to know how the comparison between files is done (I think it's comparing version number to version number), but it's not very easy to explain.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean when you say "files in drawn."  Did you mean to say "files is drawn" as in "how does TFS know how to compare files?

Resolve conflict tool is used when TFS cannot resolve the conflict on its own.

This [MS Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181433.aspx#manage_items) will walk you through how to get more detailed information and explain how the tool works.

There are a few "buckets" for [conflicts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181434%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (see below).

As for wanting video tutorials, there are a few that simply show you how to use the tool and some cursory conflicts but there are no videos that I have found that go over each conflict case type.

Conflicts are always difficult when they can't be automatically managed.  I would consider [swapping out your merge tool to a better one](http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2007/12/Better-DiffMerge-tool-for-TFS.aspx).

I hope that helps you.

> **Version Conflict**
>
> Version conflicts can occur in Team
>   Foundation version control with a
>   check-in, get, or merge operation. In
>   each case, the evolution of an item
>   along divergent paths results in a
>   conflict.
>
> ```
>   Check-in   Two users check out the latest version of a file. The
> ```
>
> first user checks in changes; this
>   creates a new version of the file.
>   When the second user tries a check-in,
>   there is a version conflict because
>   the second user's changes were not
>   made against the latest version of the
>   file.
>       *
>
> ```
>   Get   Two users check out the latest version of a file. The first
> ```
>
> user checks in changes; this creates a
>   new version of the file. When the
>   second user performs a get latest
>   operation, there is a version conflict
>   because the get latest operation is
>   trying to update the checked-out file
>   in the workspace.
>       *
>
> ```
>   Merge   A branched file has been modified in both branches. A user
> ```
>
> tries to merge changes from one branch
>   to the other. There is a version
>   conflict because the file has been
>   modified on both branches.
>
> **File Name Collision Conflict**
>
> File name collisions can occur in Team
>   Foundation version control with a
>   check-in, get, or merge operation. In
>   all three cases, the conflict results
>   when two or more items try to occupy
>   the same path in the source control
>   server.
>
> ```
>   Check-in   Two users each add a file to the same application.
> ```
>
> Coincidentally, the two users choose
>   the same name for the new files. One
>   user checks in his or her file. When
>   the second user tries a check-in,
>   there is a file name collision.
>       *
>
> ```
>   Get   Two users add files with identical names to an application. One
> ```
>
> user checks in the file. When the
>   second user tries a get latest
>   operation, there is a file name
>   collision. This is because the first
>   user's file cannot be retrieved where
>   the second user has added a file.
>       *
>
> ```
>   Merge   An application has been branched and has then been worked on
> ```
>
> in both branches. In both branches, a
>   file that has the same name has been
>   added. A user tries to merge changes
>   from one branch to the other. There is
>   a file name collision because the file
>   added to the source branch can not be
>   branched where a file has already been
>   added to the target branch.
>
> **Local overwrite conflict**
>
> Local overwrite conflicts only occur
>   in Team Foundation version control
>   during a get operation. These
>   conflicts occur when a get operation
>   tries to write over a writable file in
>   your workspace. By default, the get
>   operation will only replace files that
>   are read-only. Resolving local
>   overwrite conflicts involves either
>   overwriting the file or checking out
>   the file and merging changes.

Comment: Np, give some serious consideration to using a better merge tool- it really helps out.

Comment: SourceGear/BC2 are good compare tools(not sure if it's a good merge tool) ... is there a merge tool that you would recommend to replace the default merge tool?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say compare tool- my bad there.